# Using Ubuntu directly and through a VM

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mac, boot, virtual-machine

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible but here it goes: I need to run Ubuntu to do some development and there may be times when I'm stuck with a Windows machine or a Mac OS X machine.

My first thought was to use a thumb drive with a VM to do this however it's also possible some machines may have less ram than optimal for a VM.

Is it possible to then do the following:

- Install Ubuntu as a bootable OS onto the thumb drive itself so I can boot directly into ubuntu on a machine.
- Use the same Ubuntu installation inside of a VM on more powerful machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only a few development tools from linux on a Windows machine for some light work, consider [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). You can save some time and effort with this.

As for the original question:

> Install Ubuntu as a bootable OS onto the thumb drive itself so I can boot directly into ubuntu on a machine.

Yes, this possible. You have two options:

- Creating a Live USB Stick (similar to a Live CD). Read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13379/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-9.10-usb-flash-drive/) post for details.
- Create a persistent install that *remembers* changes that you make between reboots (unlike a live installation which gives you a clean slate every time you boot). Take a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) article for details.

Note that both the posts were written for Ubuntu 9.10, so you many need to make a few tweaks/changes if you're using some other version.

> Use the same Ubuntu installation inside of a VM on more powerful machines.

This is also possible. You can install Ubuntu on a VM on one of the machines and "export" the installed image for use on the 2nd machine (I know VirtualBox offers this [functionality](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf) for sure, though its a little slow). This approach will work if you have only a few machines that need this VM environment.

Comment: Thanks. This helps but I ended up going for just using VMWare as some of these options weren't quite working out and VMWare seems to work fine for now.